# When to use radians or degrees?

Tags: trigonometry, angle

I am having trouble with a task because I am having a hard time understanding when to use rad or deg.

The question is:
"If $A$ is an obtuse angle in a triangle and $\sin A = \dfrac{5}{13}$, calculate the exact value of $\sin (2A)$."

How do I know if my calculator should be set to degrees or radians in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The units of measure for $A$ have nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: You should get the same answer for $\sin(2A)$ in both cases.  Different $A$ (one in radians, the other in degrees) but the same $\sin(2A)$.  But note.  You need the **exact value**, not just 10 digits of an approximation to it.  Thus, I would say do not use your calculator at all.  Use your brain!

Comment: When in a Physics problem they give you a certain unit of measurement (one or several), you have to act on those measures. In your mathematical problem the thing is similar: if you do not get radians or degrees then you answer in the abstract too.

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is, use radians in any mathematics class at or above the level of Calculus, also when talking to a mathematician;  use degrees everywhere else.

Comment: In this question, since the final answer has been designed to be a rational number. you are supposed to provide the exact value of $A$, You need not and in fact should not compute $A$ at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that in the context of the specific question you cited, it is immaterial as to whether the angle $A$ is specified in degrees of radians.

From basic trigonometry, you can evaluate $\sin 2A$ directly in terms of $\sin A$ as

$$\sin 2A = 2\sin A\cos A = 2\sin A \sqrt{1-\sin^2 A}$$

The broader question as to whether an angle should be specified in radians or not depends, again, on the context.

Comment: Thank you very much